# Ament/Colcon: Share variable between package CMakeLists

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, colcon, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to share a filepath variable between the `CMakeLists` of two packages.

When I set in the first `CMakeLists` a variable using the following ways:

```
set(varABC "x" CACHE STRING "Description")
set( ENV{varDEF} x )
```

It won't appear in the second `CmakeLists` the following way:

```
find_package(packageA REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "${varABC}")
message(STATUS "${varDEF}")
```

Anybody knows how to do that the right way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310518/ament/colcon:-share-variable-between-package-cmakelists/) by [Flautz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33500/flautz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each package is a separate CMake project. For each a separate CMake invocation is being used. So variables set in one are *not* available in the other.

The `ament_cmake` function `ament_package` has an argument `CONFIG_EXTRAS` (see https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/2d65d41e047e203cd0531df9b0987d8aaea7d6ca/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package.cmake#L24-L32). You can provide you own CMake file which will be included when other packages find your package with `find_package()`.

You will find examples how to use the argument in various packages (e.g. in [rclcpp](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/a54a32915313960497bda2d601cdf98e9f2e9bf0/rclcpp/CMakeLists.txt#L404-L406)).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flautz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33500/flautz/) on 2018-12-12**:
Thanks, that seems to be the right thing!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-12-12**:
Please mark the answer as correct (using the checkmark below the voting) if it answers the question. It just helps others to find answered questions in the future. Thanks.